# Debug Quasar V2 using WebStorm 2021

Tags: webstorm, quasar-framework, quasar

I have set the following in `quasar.conf.js`:

```
build: {
     devtool: 'source-map'
}
```

Then I run `quasar serve` in terminal and run debug using WebStorm with the following configuration but the breakpoint is not triggered.

What can be the issue?

[image]

Comment: see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4409692650514-Debug-Quasar-V2-using-WebStorm-2021?page=1#community_comment_4409782546962

Comment: were you able to get it to work? Linked support-ticket seems to be a dead end. Despite setting `source-map` I can see multiple .vue files generated out of one original. I'm running `quasar dev` - without success.